# How to change this "Variaition" hook in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change the woocommerce_before_single_variation - I dont want to have the variation above the add to cart because i have a sticky add to cart on mobile - so i want the variable to be in single product Summary - but i cant find the way to do it - Can someone help me ?

i tried many different way but none worked!
// Remove the variable product form from its default location
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );

// Add the variable product form to the single product summary hook
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 25 );